# Use stirlings approximation to prove inequality.

Tags: inequality, approximation, factorial, gamma-function

I have come across this statement in a text on finite elements.  I can give you the reference if that will be useful.  The text mentions that the inequality follows from Stirling's formula.  I can't prove it to myself but I think it is true from checking values with Mathematica.

Let $p,k\in \mathbb{N}$ with $k\le p$.  Then we have

$$\frac{(p-k)!}{(p+k)!} \le \left(\frac{\theta}{p}\right)^{2k},\, \theta = \left(\frac{e}{2}\right)^{k/p}.$$

Does anyone have an idea of how to get this inequality from Stirling's approximation?

This is my attempt at a solution.  To build intuition, let's look at the case $k=p$ we have

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{(p-k)!}{(p+k)!} &= \frac{1}{(2p)!} \\
&\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{\exp(2p)}{(2p)^{2p+1/2} } \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left(\frac{e}{2} \right)^{2p} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \frac{1}{p^{2p}} \frac{1}{p^{1/2}}\\
& \le   \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \left( \frac{e}{2} \right)^{2p} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{1}{p^{2p}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \frac{\theta}{p} \right)^{2k}\\
&\le \left( \frac{\theta}{p} \right)^{2k}
\end{align*}
$$

And this is what we wanted to show.

Now let's look at the case $k=p-1$, then we get

$$
\begin{align*}
  \frac{(p-k)!}{(p+k)!} &= 
  \frac{1}{(2p-1)!} \\
&\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{\exp( 2p-1)}{ (2p-1)^{2p-1/2}} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{\exp(2p-1)}{2^{2p-1/2}} \frac{1} {(p-1/2)^{2p-1/2} }\\
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(\frac{e}{2}  \right)^{2p-1} \frac{1}{(p-1/2)^{2p-1/2}}\\
&\le \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \left( \frac{e}{2} \right)^{2p-1} \frac{1}{(p-1/2)^{2p-1}} \\
&\le ??
\end{align*}$$

This is where I am stuck.  For the $k=p-1$ case, I can multiply and divide by $(\frac{e}{2})^{3-2/p}$ to get something of the correct form, but then it seems I would have to to prove that for all $p$

$$\left(\frac{e}{2}\right)^{3-2/p} \frac{1}{(p-1/2)^{2p-1}} \le 1.$$  This seems like a dead end to me.  And this is still just a special case of the general result.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For
$\left(\frac{e}{2}\right)^{3-2/p} \frac{1}{(p-1/2)^{2p-1}} 
\le 1
$,

$\begin{array}\\
(p-1/2)^{2p-1}
&=p^{2p-1}(1-1/(2p))^{2p-1}\\
&\approx p^{2p-1}(1/e)(1-1/(2p))^{-1}
\quad\text{since }(1-1/(2p))^{2p} \approx 1/e\\
\end{array}
$

so

$\begin{align*}\\
\left(\frac{e}{2}\right)^{3-2/p} \frac{1}{(p-1/2)^{2p-1}} 
&\approx \left(\frac{e}{2}\right)^{3-2/p}\frac1{p^{2p-1}}e(1-1/(2p))\\
&< \left(\frac{e}{2}\right)^{3-2/p}\frac1{p^{2p-1}}e\\
&< \left(\frac{e}{2}\right)^{3}\frac1{p^{2p-1}}e\\
&= \frac{e^4}{8p^{2p-1}}\\
&\ll 1 \quad\text{for } p > 5
\end{align*}
$

So this inequality
is very strongly true.